# Swift SFSymbol unexpectedly found nil for UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimage

I have a bug that I am not understanding.

All devices I have tested are not having this issue. However, on `ipad mini 4 iOS 13.4` I am receiving the error: `Swift runtime failure: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

```
let image = UIImage(systemName: "chevron.forward")?
```

I am programmatically assigning the value on viewDidLoad(). All devices I have tested do not have this issue but mini 4.

I thought SF symbols work for iOS 13+ but I can seem to understand why the crash is happening on the iPad mini 4.

Apple states,

> "SF Symbols are available in iOS 13 and later, macOS 11 and later,
> watchOS 6 and later, and tvOS 13 and later."

But does not share that only particular symbols can be accessed in different iOS versions. [Reference](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sf-symbols/overview/?changes=_5_1)

Comment: This is a conditionally unwrapped line, so should not crash.  Are you sure it isn't crashing somewhere else where you force unwrap the value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple has added new symbol at various times. The `chevron.forward` symbol was added in iOS 14, which is why it's crashing in iOS 13 for you.